# Real Conjugacy Class, group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group of odd order n. Suppose that g is in a real conjugacy class C (a real conjugacy class C is a conjugacy class so that $C$ = $C^{-1}$ ). So $h^{−1}gh = g^{−1}$ for some h $\in G$.

*Why can we follow from that*: $h^{−2}gh^2 = g$ ?

This means $h^2 \in C_G(g)$. Since n is odd, the order of h is odd, say
2k + 1. It follows that h = ($h^2)^{k+1}$

*Why can we follow from that*: h $\in C_G(g)$ ?

Thankfull for any help.

Comment: Why was my answer unaccepted? You ask two questions in one ...

Comment: it was unintentionally

Comment: Ah good, thanks Marcel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of $|G|$ is odd, say $G=2m-1$, for some positive integer $m$. Hence by Lagrange $h^{|G|}=1=(h^2)^m \cdot h^{-1}$. It follows that $h=(h^2)^m$, so if $h^2 \in C_G(g)$, then $h \in C_G(g)$.

Comment: If $h^2$ is in the subgroup then any power of it is too.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equality as $h^{-1}g^{-1}h=g$ and now(here’s the trick!) replace the g in $h^{-1}g^{-1}h$ with $h^{-1}g^{-1}h$ (because g and $h^{-1}g^{-1}h$ are equal). So we get that $g=h^{-1}g^{-1}h=h^{-1}(h^{-1}g^{-1}h)^{-1}h=h^{-2}gh^2$ keep replacing g inside $h^{-2}gh^2$ with $h^{-1}g^{-1}h$ to eventually get that $h^{-2k}gh^{2k}=g$, but $h^{2k}=h^{-1}$ so by the last equality $h$ and $g$ commute

Comment: You get $g = h^{-2k}gh^{2k}$ after $2k $ substitutions, not after $ k$, and the reason you get $ g $ and not $ g^{-1}$ is because $ 2k $ is even and after an even number of substitutions you get g while after an odd number of substitutions you get $g^{-1}$

Comment: you are partly right because it should be $hg^{-1}h^{-1}=g$ but the argument still goes through ;)

Comment: Actually if you substitute g you get $hg^{-1}h^{-1}=h(hg^{-1}h^{-1})^{-1}h^{-1}=h^2gh^{-2}$